# Unity% Mechanim animation does not move straight

Tags: unity, animation

I've imported a mixamo animation into unity5.
I've also set up a trigger to move the character forward, the wierd thing is that when the animation finishes his rotation is not perfectly straight. 
So the next time he moves forward his rotation is a bit to the left so eventually he ends up running in a circle.

Is there a setting to assure that my character will only move forward when he during moving forward, or should I programatically change these parameters to assure that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Animations in the model Import Settings, check the **Root Transform Rotation**. There you can specify an offset until the character's forward direction is exactly at (0.000, 0.000, 1.000) - the last number may differ, since this indicates the speed at which the root motion moves in a certain direction.

The direction is indicated above or below these settings. I currently don't have a character to test it out, but remember this was how I worked around the issue.

Comment: Great. Let me know if it works out for you. Otherwise there may be some other things you can try.